Trouble with point visibility at boolean intersection edge with Geo-nodes. Trying to make a disintegration effect
Im trying to make a disintegration effect using geo nodes. My plan is that when my boolean intersects the plane, particles appear at the intersection. My problem now is that when I’m trying to make the point only visible right at the edge of the plane where my boolean intersects it, I can’t get it to work. (Less than is set to 0.001) What could be causing this?


The file:


assuming that this...

...is what you want, you can use this node setup:

Note 1: always try to avoid boolean nodes, because they make your node tree slow. So use proximity whenever it is possible.
Note 2: Delete the link i marked with the blue x -> i just wanted to show the plane so that you can better see how it works.
With the proximity to faces, i get a distance to the surface. With the greater than node, i can delete all distributed points on my object, so that only points near the surface stay on it.
Hope that helps.

Not on a PC right now: could you also use the proximity for the Density of the Distribute Points on Faces node instead of deleting generated points? Like for example distance < 0.001 and multiplying the result with 800?

Thats a really good idea!

@GordonBrinkmann: i didn't try either, but i assume: yes

Also thank you for the solution! Chris
